# C# & Oracle Query Database with resepct to an organization

Tags: c#, oracle

I am writing a C# application to pull specific items from an Oracle database. These items are specific to an organization inside of the Oracle E-Business Suite R12. The goal is to be able to query this but I have zero idea how!

The image below shows how the folder structure is laid out. As you can see targetted table is in

`Data Table 2 - > Folder C - > Table Found`

[image]

Once Targetted Table is Selected, a new dialog opens, for choosing an organization. For this example we will take `Org 2`

[image]

The C# Code I have written:

```
OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection();
// Oracle for items: Data Table 2 - > Folder C -> Targetted Table -> Item -> Find
con.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = host.company.com)" + 
                        "(PORT = 1521))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = Data Table 2))); " +
                        "Password= WhiteRabbit1! ;User ID=Mr_Anderson";
con.Open();
Console.WriteLine("Connected to Oracle" + con.ServerVersion);

OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT [Level], [Item], [Description] FROM [Targetted Table]";
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (dr.Read())
    // Add data
```

Which outputs the error:

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-12541: TNS:no listener'
>
> At the Line: con.Open();

EDIT: Changed `HOST = host.company.com` to `HOST = host.company.com\` and we get a new error output!

> Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleException: 'ORA-12545: Connect failed because target host or object does not exist'

I am trying to follow this guide: https://o7planning.org/en/10509/connecting-to-oracle-database-using-csharp-without-oracle-client#a1814792

But not sure what step messed up the code. My guess is the port, but I don't know where to look for that. Saw an article that said use 1521 for database access

Comment: You have to find the Oracle Server and find out if it is running and what port it is using.  The error could indicate the server is not running, the IP address of the server is wrong, or the port number is wrong.

Comment: Would that be all done through the command line? I only have access to the Business side where the login I have doesn't give me Admin rights, basically cant find out port or ip via my credentials. @jdweng

Comment: What command line?  Where is the ORACLE database running?  Is it automatically started as a service on a machine or started by a command line?  When Oracle is started the port number to listen must be set (or using the default port number).

Comment: Im not sure how the Oralce system is running. I access it through a web url.

Comment: The Cloud is connecting to the database so your code doesn't have to connect.  You need to find the documentation for cloud to get the query syntax.  Your query will be a URL with parameters or a HTTP PUT Request.